# SNMP MIB Visualizer recommendations?

Tags: snmp, mib

Are there any free visualization tools for MIBs?  I've been assigned some SNMP trap normalization/enrichment work and been given Cisco ONS 15454s to start with.  The MIBs seem more complex than others I have seen.  Lots of object cross-references, including some to objects that are defined in other MIBs and exported.  A quick example of trying to trace down the port number of an alarm:

Alarm definition:

```
Cerent454AlarmEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
    cerent454AlarmIndex          INTEGER,
    cerent454AlarmObjectType     Cerent454EntityClass,
    cerent454AlarmSlotNumber     INTEGER,
    cerent454AlarmPortNumber     CerentPortNumber,
    cerent454AlarmLineNumber     INTEGER,
    cerent454AlarmObjectIndex    INTEGER,
    cerent454AlarmType           Cerent454AlarmType,
    cerent454AlarmState          CerentNotificationClass,
    cerent454AlarmTimeStamp      TimeStamp,
    cerent454AlarmObjectName     DisplayString,
    cerent454AlarmAdditionalInfo DisplayString
}
```

CerentPortNumber references from the same file (CERENT-454.mib):

```
IMPORTS
    (...)
    CerentPortNumber
        FROM CERENT-TC

(...)
cerent454AlarmPortNumber OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      CerentPortNumber
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION 
        "This will indicate what is the port
         of the object which raised this alarm."
    ::= { cerent454AlarmEntry 40 }
```

The actual syntax for CerentPortNumber, from CERENT-TC.mib:

```
CerentPortNumber ::=
      INTEGER
      {        unknown   (1),
               port0     (5),
               port1    (10),
               port2    (20),
               (...)
               port62  (620),
               port63  (630),
               port64  (640),
               portAll (10240)
             }
```

Maybe this isn't as complex as it feels, but this is just one small example.  It feels like there should be a GUI-based "explorer" type app that would allow me to see these references easily without a lot of back and forth between files and locations in files.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

I use [iReasoning's MIB Browser](http://www.ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml).

Comment: this tool is very useful, and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The one I used to use was [MIB Browser](http://www.snmp-browser.com/).

But looking for MIB viewer on google gives you lots of other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you can use Mgsoft-MIB Browser trail version for some extent.

Regards
Haranadh

Answer (score 0):

You can use tkmib and snmpb in Linux-land.